# SWIFT 4.1 Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm retrieving mapView annotations posted in Firebase to show them on map, but while converting String values for latitude and longitude to recombine them into CLLocationCoordinates2D I get the error. I don't understand why, because in another function I use the same method but getting the values from arrays but I don't get the error. Also on retrieving the data I would like to also use the key value from firebase as initialiser for my annotations. But I get two more errors Use of unresolved identifier 'firebaseKey' and Use of unresolved identifier 'recombinedCoordinate' for initialisers. Here're the function:

```
func displayAlerts() {
        // FIREBASE: Reference
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        // FIREBASE:Retrieve posts and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String]
            if let actualData = data {
                let dataLatitude = data!["Latitude"]
                let dataLongitude = data!["Longitude"]
                self.alertIconToDisplay = data!["Description"]

                let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
                let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
                var recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)
                print("Firebase post retrieved !")
                self.dummyFunctionToFoolFirebaseObservers()
            }
            let dataKey = snapshot.key as? String
            if let firebaseKey = dataKey {
                print("Longitude DataKey is \(String(describing: dataKey))")
                print("Longitude Actual DataKey is \(String(describing: firebaseKey))")

                self.dummyFunctionToFoolFirebaseObservers()
            }

            print("fir long \((snapshot.value!, snapshot.key))")
            userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: self.alertIconToDisplay, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.userAlertAnnotation)  
        })
    }
```

Here's the annotation model :

```
class UserAlert: NSObject , MKAnnotation {
    var type: String?
    var firebaseKey: String?
    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(type:String, coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, firebaseKey: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.firebaseKey = firebaseKey
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I understand that the error on the initialisers are because initialisation occurs in key closures, but how then I incorporate all data into initialiser ?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: userAlertAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "")    //  CHANGE FOR NEW ANNOTATION : FULL DATA

        //added if statement for displaying user location blue dot
        if annotation is MKUserLocation{
            return nil
        } else {


            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: alertIconToDisplay!)                        //    choose the image to load

            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.27, y: 0.27)
            annotationView.transform = transform
            return annotationView
        }
    }



 func postAlertNotification() {

        // to set next notification id as the position it will have in array ( because first position is 0 ) we use the array.count as value


        let latitude = alertNotificationLatitude
        let longitude = alertNotificationLongitude
        let alertType = alertNotificationType

        let post: [String:String] = [//"Date" : date as! String,
                                     //"Time" : time as! String,
                                     "Latitude" : latitude as! String,
                                     "Longitude" : longitude as! String,
                                     "Description" : alertType as! String]

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
  }
```

Comment: Is Latitude and Longitude being stored as Strings in Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the topic says that you can't create a Double from an optional String which is true.
To solve it force unwrap the values for `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

But the main issue is a scope issue, all variables used in the initializer must be in the **same** scope. You can *flatten* the scope with `guard` statements:

```
...
databaseHandle = ref?.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        defer { self.dummyFunctionToFoolFirebaseObservers() }
        guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }
        guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }

        //                let date = data!["Date"]
        //                let time = data!["Time"]
        let dataLatitude = data["Latitude"]!
        let dataLongitude = data["Longitude"]!
        self.alertIconToDisplay = data["Description"]!

        let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
        let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
        let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

        print("Firebase post retrieved !")

        //                self .keyaLon = dataKey
        //                self.keyaLonArray.append(firebaseKey)

        print("Longitude Actual DataKey is \(String(describing: firebaseKey))")

        print("fir long \((snapshot.value!, snapshot.key))")
        self.userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: self.alertIconToDisplay, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.userAlertAnnotation)


    })
```

Comment: I now see the problem. thanks for the explanation. now I'm facing this problem. all icons are the same. the last in the list in Firebase realtime database.  If I pos another one after loading up it displays the chosen one. but go back to the previous viewcontoller and get back into mapVC than all icons are the same as I just posted.
I'll add in the description the mapView function where I assign the image and the annotation to use.

Comment: I asked a new question for the previous comment, after realising that I shouldn't have edited this question title. so I just put again the old title.